# placing a triangle in first quadrant

Tags: geometry

I was trying to prove the following but I am unable to :
I have a triangle, whose all three sides have integer length. One vertex of the triangle is at $(0,0)$. 
Both the coordinates of other two vertices are integer ( the other two vertices can be in any quadrant of $x$-$y$ plane ). 
Now I want to place the same triangle (triangle with same shape )solely in the first quadrant in $x$-$y$ plane. The triangle has to be placed such that any one vertex coincides with $(0,0)$ and other two vertices lie in first quadrant and coincide with some points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that all $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ are integers.

PS: My question is in reference to the last optimization (optimizing the brute force) in the editorial of the problem Find Polygons [SRM 600 Div 1 500](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+599)

Comment: what does "integral length" mean? is it a typo for "integer"?

Comment: This is clearly not possible if the triangle is equilateral with side $1$.

Comment: @chouaib sorry integer it it.corrected it.

Comment: Actually, "integral length" is correct, "integral" being the adjectival form of "integer".

Comment: As @David pointed out, this proposition is not true. Are there any other restrictions on the triangle? For example, it would work if the triangle had to be a right triangle.

Comment: @PeterOlson sorry posted the incomplete problem stupid of me. update it

Comment: @David sorry , posted incomplete problem.updated it.

Comment: For this problem, does "first quadrant" include the boundary?  In other words, can some of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ be zero?

Comment: @David yes boundary is included in 1st quadrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$Let the coordinates of the vertices of the given triangle be $\\a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $\\b=(b_1,b_2)$ and $\\c=(c_1,c_2)$, labelled so that $a_1\le b_1\le c_1$.

Case 1, $a_2\le c_2$.  Then either $b_2<c_2$ or $b_2\ge c_2$, and the triangles
$$\\c'=(0,0)\,,\ \\a'=\\c-\\a\,,\ \\b'=\\c-\\b\ \ $$
or
$$\\a'=(0,0)\,,\ \\c'=\\c-\\a\,,\ \\b'=\\b-\\a\ ,$$
respectively, satisfy your conditions.

Case 2, $a_2>c_2$.  Similarly, take
$$\\c'=(0,0)\,,\ \\b'=(b_2-c_2,c_1-b_1)\,,\ \\a'=(a_2-c_2,c_1-a_1)\qquad
  \hbox{if $b_2\ge c_2$}$$
or
$$\\a'=(0,0)\,,\ \\b'=(a_2-b_2,b_1-a_1)\,,\ \\c'=(a_2-c_2,c_1-a_1)\qquad
  \hbox{if $b_2<c_2$.}$$

I have assumed that you are not allowed to reflect the given triangle but only to rotate it.  If you are allowed to reflect it there are probably simpler solutions.

Comment: really cool thanks a lot could never have come up with such neat explanation on my own thanks alot again :)